# How to find dependency providing annotation processor

Tags: java, gradle, classpath

I am running a build with latest Gradle version (v4.6) in a project with a lot of classpath dependencies. I get:

> Putting annotation processors on the compile classpath has been
>   deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please add
>   them to the processor path instead.

How can I find the offending dependency/ies (in a reasonable way)?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found so far is to add-hoc the following code myself to the build script:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    doFirst {
        effectiveAnnotationProcessorPath.each { maybeJar ->
            if (maybeJar.file) {
                println "Doing: " + maybeJar.name
                zipTree(maybeJar).matching {
                    include 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
                } each {
                    processorConfigFile -> 
                    println "Annotation processor(s) found in $maybeJar.name:"
                    println processorConfigFile.filterLine { it =~ /^(?!#)/ }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*(based on [this Gradle forum answer](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/incremental-compile-with-gradle-3-4-2-rc-2-not-working/21526/8))*

Comment: Since you only need this once to move the found dependencies to another configuration, I like the solution.